# How to Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipeline for PowerBuilder 2017 R3 project, is it even possible?

Tags: azure-devops, powerbuilder, azure-pipelines-build-task, powerbuilder-2017

> **Summary**

Recently migrated PB126 apps to PB2017 and changed source control to Azure DevOps Git.

Now, I'd like to integrate Azure DevOps CI/CD Build Pipeline to the app dev life-cycle.

> **jenkins**

I know it's feasible to configure jenkins CI server so it builds PB2017 projects.

[Continuous Integration with PowerBuilder 2017, Bonobo Git and Jenkins](https://www.brucearmstrong.org/2017/07/continuous-integration-with.html)

My problem here's I can't get it to work on a local Docker container and make it accessible to the outside world (Internet) so Azure DevOps can trigger its build action. Supposedly, it's a Docker for Windows thing which Docker handles differently from the Linux-based Docker.

> **Azure DevOps Pipeline**

As per this link, [Azure Pipelines is the CI/CD solution for any language, any platform, any cloud](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-pipelines-is-the-ci-cd-solution-for-any-language-any-platform-any-cloud/), it says *any language*, which makes me believe it's feasible to build PB2017 projects using Azure DevOps Pipelines.

The fact is that I'm totally new to CI/CD in terms of implementing it myself. I've experienced it in many projects where I wasn't responsible to implement it. Now I am. I've been on it since a few days now, and I do want it to work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You may wish to post this to the Appeon Developer Community forum on Appeon.com as well.

Comment: "My problem here's I can't get it to work on a local Docker container and make it accessible to the outside world (Internet) so Azure DevOps can trigger its build action." What's that? Why Docker is needed?

Comment: @LexLi, because of testing purposes. Using a containerized Jenkins CI/CD server will isolate it from my local machine. Nothing to install of Jenkins on my local machine whatsoever. Those are the benefits I'm after. Because once I'm done with my test, I will no longer need Jenkins on my local machine and will rather use it on the company's server. But first, I need to test and learn how it all works together.

Comment: You should split this huge question to only a smaller ones, which might then turn out to be answered many times before, or simple enough to be answered by yourself, such as 1) How to prepare an agent machine for Azure Pipelines (a full machine, or a Docker container). 2) How to install PB2017 there so later you can built the projects. 3) How to automate the manual steps on Azure Pipelines.

Comment: @LexLi, thanks for you suggestion. I shall give it a try soon. Thanks for giving me examples on how I could break down this question either, this helps me better understand the segments of my question. I appreciate your time. :)

Answer (score -1):

The Appeon offical user forum: https://community.appeon.com/index.php/qna/q-a

Comment: Nearly all questions I encountered in regards to continuous integration, Azure DevOps, etc. have no solutions just yet. And the official Appeon forum looks rather useless, even though it's official. Aside, this doesn't really answer the question, so I'd see your answer more like a comment. Just Saying. :)

Comment: Besides, thanks for your input whatsoever. I appreciate you trying to help. :)

Comment: At least on the Appeon forum you won't have to worry about being labelled as off-topic.